# cannot compile spring-security-core because of ehcache

Tags: spring, grails, ehcache

I'm trying to add spring-security to my grail project but it fails at compilation.
Here are the plugins i have in BuildConfig.groovy:
` // plugins for the build system only
        build ":tomcat:7.0.54"

```
    // plugins for the compile step
    compile ":scaffolding:2.1.1"
    compile ':cache:1.1.6'
    compile ":asset-pipeline:1.8.11"
    compile ":mongodb:3.0.1"
    compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC3"


    // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
    //runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.5.4" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.16"
    runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"`
```

The compilation failed, I got this fatal error message:

> Fatal error during compilation java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/ehcache/config/CacheConfiguration

I followed the instructions [here](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/tutorials.html) but get stuck after the 'grails compile' step.
I tried adding *ehcache* dependency in the plugins list but then it says that it couldn't be downloaded. I don't know what to do. The project is very simple, I've just beginning the tutorial from the link I gave before. 
I just uninstalled hibernate and installed mongodb instead.

Comment: Ok, uninstalling hibernate wasn't a good idea since spring-security-core need it apparently. If I want to use mongo-db instead for my entire grail project do I have to systemically add 'static mapWith = 'mongo' in all my domain classes or is there a way to set it globally for the entire project?

Comment: a complete example is here http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=1992; if you are using only mongo (no hiberante) you don't have to write the mapWith.  And your problem seems to be related to grails 2.4 as Burts code works with 2.3 but i get the same error as you once i update it.

Comment: Do you have any other plugins installed except as given in the description, like mail plugin?

Comment: @0alpha0 Is your problem solved? Even I'm struck, can you help?

Comment: I moved to another project. I cannot tell you right now. But did you try VeGo answer? If it works tell me and I will validate his answer. Or do what cfrick said, downgrade to 2.3

Comment: Just blindly accept his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add *ehcache* to the dependencies not plugins.

```
dependencies {
    compile "net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:2.4.8"
}
```

I don't think spring-security-core needs hibernate.